# Android listview control loses value while scrolling

Tags: android, listview, adapter

When I slightly scroll my listview down and scroll up again the rows that have been out of view loses value (edittext) please see the images below:
[pictures taken directly from htc m7 smartphone]

[image]

And when when I focus and display the keyboard the values return as it should be !

[image]

I don't need textwatcher because the edit's value is from my static array.

**Here is my adapter:**

```
public class SearchableItemsAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable
{
    ArrayList<MyInvoiceItems> filteredData = new ArrayList<MyInvoiceItems>();
    MyInvoiceItems temp;
    private ItemFilter mFilter;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    //
    public SearchableItemsAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<MyInvoiceItems> data) {
        filteredData = data;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }
    //
    public int getCount() {
        return  filteredData.size();
    }
    //
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return filteredData.get(position);
    }
    //
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    //        
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        final ViewHolderItems itemsholder;            
        if(convertView==null)
        {
            convertView=mInflater.inflate(R.layout.lstcstmrinvoicepopupitems,parent,false);
            itemsholder=new ViewHolderItems();
            itemsholder.iTaken=(CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.inv_popupTaken);
            itemsholder.iName=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.inv_popupName);
            itemsholder.iQuan=(EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.inv_popupQuan);
            itemsholder.iPrice=(EditText) convertView.findViewById(R.id.inv_popupPrice);
            itemsholder.iTotal=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.inv_popupTotal);
            convertView.setTag(itemsholder);
        }
        else
        {
            itemsholder=(ViewHolderItems) convertView.getTag();
        }
        if(filteredData!=null) {                
            itemsholder.iTaken.setChecked(false);
            if (filteredData.get(position).getTaken() == 1)
                itemsholder.iTaken.setChecked(true);
            itemsholder.iName.setText(filteredData.get(position).getItem_desc());
            itemsholder.iQuan.setText(filteredData.get(position).getItem_num().toString());
            itemsholder.iPrice.setText(filteredData.get(position).getItem_cost().toString());
            itemsholder.iTotal.setText(filteredData.get(position).getAmountTotal());               
        }
        //---
        return convertView;
    }
    //
    public class ViewHolderItems {
        CheckBox iTaken;
        TextView iName;
        EditText iQuan;
        EditText iPrice;
        TextView iTotal;
    }      
}
```

By the way anybody knows why there are **two** blinking cursors (at second image before and after the number 5)?

Answer (score 0):

Finally after fighting two days, and searching the internet for solution I thought that there is a problem with my code (the adapter maybe) BUT actually the main cause for this behavior WAS the .xml design that  represent every row in my list, I used a table for every component and after changing that to RelativeLayout and put every control directly on the RelativeLayout It works as charm, I don't believe that the design of .xml layout may affect my view. but I have learned a lot from this problem :-)